# Hive Grouping and calculating average by calculating distinct

Tags: hadoop, hive

Folks we have one wired requirement in HIVE and we are not able to write query for the same

Basically we have following data.

```
CUSTOMER_NAME PRODUCT_NAME PRICE OCCURANCE ID
customer1,    product1,    20,       1
customer1,    product2,    30,       2
customer1,    product1,    25,       3
customer1,    product1,    20,       1
customer1,    product2,    20,       2
```

Basically what we have to do is list the average price for (customer_name,product_name) for single  occurance.

e.g. for combination (customer1,product1) price for product1 is 
25+20/2(no of distinct occurences for customer(1 and 3)) = 22.5. But as we want to group by PRODUCT_NAME also we donot know how to calculate the distinct occurance. I have marked the query with [] bracket where we feel we need to do some change.

Other aspect is the inner query here we want to select customers where their average price will fall in to top 5 for distinct occurrencs. ( This works properly as group by clause is having only one attribute CUSTOMER_NAME)

```
select customer_name,product_name,[sum(price)/count(distinct(occurance_id))]
from customer_prd cprd
Join (select customer_name,sum(price)/count(distinct(occurance id))
order by sum group  
by customer_name limit 5)
cprdd
where cprd.customer_name = cprdd.customer_name group by cprd.customer_name,cprd.product_name
```

output expected.

```
 customer1,product1, 20 (avg for occurance ID 1) + 25(average for occurance ID 2)/2 = 22.5
 customer1,product2, 30 + 20/2 = 25
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, it seems like the only trouble here is that you have duplicates. If you remove duplicate occurrences, then it's a simple group by and average:

```
select customer_name, product_name, avg(price)
from (
  select distinct customer_name, product_name, price, occurance_id from cprd
) t
group by customer_name, product_name
```

Comment: Please check inner query. I need to select customer based on the price sum group by only customer and later group them by customer name product name.

Comment: I have updated expected output to make in more clear.